# How to use Dynamic IP to request connect with socket in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

```
public void connectContent()
{    
    client= new TcpClient();      
 
    var result=client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4"), 12000,null,null);  
    var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    
    if(success){
        Debug.Log("ok "+playerID);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("fail");
    }
}
```

I have a project developed for over 5 months, and it always can connect in the expected way.

But today it can't connect to server, after I changed the IP `192.168.1.3` to `192.168.1.4`, it works. I don't know why and how this happen. Static IP in code seems unsafe when some outside problem happen will influence the client IP.

How to use Dynamic IP rather than write the static IP in code?

Comment: it seems you'll have to learn about the [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

Comment: As Franz Gleichmann noted you can use a DNS (basically a mapping between a name and an IP, i.e stackoverflow.com <-> 151.101.1.69) or use a config file and load the IP at runtime

Comment: An IP address is a string so you can input the string to project like any other string.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your IP (192.168.xx.xx), you're working on a local network.

You should use the device's `host-name` to connect to the device. If this is not possible: make the `IP` `static` by configuring the machine's IP or the `DHCP entry`.

##### Example with host name:

You can use the overload like this - make sure to substitute "player1" with the actual host name:

```
var result=client.BeginConnect("player1", 12000,null,null);
```

See: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.beginconnect?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcpclient-beginconnect(system-string-system-int32-system-asynccallback-system-object)).

---

##### More context and explanation:

On a local network, a device `IP`s might change over time, which is perfectly fine. It is not a problem or an error.

Devices have an IP, like "192.168.1.4", which might change. Devices will also have a `host-name`; e.g.: "XperiaBox" or "RadioMediaStreamer".

The `host-names` on your network can be found when you look onto the network (e.g.; if you're on windows through windows explorer -> network), or in your `DHCP server` (often your router).

If you use this `host-name` to connect to the device, the network router (often acting as an DNS as well) will take care of resolving the IP for you. In that sense you easily avoid having to deal with the changing IPs.

So, Assuming you're on a local network you will have a couple of options:

- use the target machines `host name` and use this overload of [BeginConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.beginconnect?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcpclient-beginconnect(system-string-system-int32-system-asynccallback-system-object)) . This will only work if the `host name` is known to the network, **or**
- make the "192.168.1.4" address `static`, so it never changes. You can configure this in the target machine's IP settings or in the DHCP server (based on host name or MAC address)

Other options on a local network are possible, but I would avoid them because it's often an indication something is off.

If you're connecting to lets say high dynamic devices (like an app on mobile phones on you network) - its better to configure the app on the phone to connect to the central system.

---

Using the host name will also work when you expand the usage to the public internet. In that case: it's easiest is to go with a static public IP and a DNS entry. It works the same, the DNS entry will act as your host-name.

Comment: @heinzQ: glad it worked. Please note that thanks is expressed by up-voting if it was helpful and/or mark as answer wen it answered your question